# How to set the end value of <c:forEach begin="1" end="?"> tag based on Selected DropDown

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

```
1)    <select onChange="showList(this.value);">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select> 

2)<script type="text/javascript">
    function showList(value){
    var endValue=value;
    }
  </script>
```

what i want is I want to set the value of end is the selcted value of dropdown

```
3)<c:forEach begin="1" end="? Here I want to set the endValue">
    <h1>print data<h1>
   </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<c:forEach>` is a jstl tag that's evaluated on the server side, so you would need to reload the page for the user's input to affect the evaluation of that tag.  You could do that with a form post when the `select` is changed, as in the example below.  This could be done in different ways, but there's no way around the fact that you need to go back to the server.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showList(){
        document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" id="myform">
        <select onChange="showList();" name="myselect">
            <option value="1" <c:if test="${param.myselect eq 1}">selected="selected"</c:if>>1</option>
            <option value="2" <c:if test="${param.myselect eq 2}">selected="selected"</c:if>>2</option>
            <option value="3" <c:if test="${param.myselect eq 3}">selected="selected"</c:if>>3</option>
            <option value="4" <c:if test="${param.myselect eq 4}">selected="selected"</c:if>>4</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <c:if test="${not empty param.myselect}">
        <c:forEach begin="1" end="${param.myselect}">
            <h1>print data</h1>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks For your Suggestion,Is there Any Other Way, Because I don't want to reload the page.

Comment: Like I said, there's no way around it if you need to use the `<c:forEach>` tag.  If all you need to do is write "print data" multiple times, you could eliminate the c:forEach and do it all client-side in javascript.